# Random 404 on any page

Tags: 404-error

I just used Softaculous to install WP on my shared host. When configuring my site, whether it's at /wp-admin/ or any other page of the site, including home, it randomly throws 404. In which case, I wait 5-10 seconds, refresh and it usually goes away after a couple refreshed.

```
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

All plugins are disabled and I haven't had time to customize anything yet.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Seems like an issue with your host. If you see your server's 404 page, those requests aren't getting routed to WordPress, the problem is further upstream.

Comment: Having multiple local environments running can do this if they all have the same address

Answer (score 0):

As @Milo said, I'd suspect the folks at your hosting place. You might also look in your hosting 'cpanel' for the '404' settings.